# How to refer to generated source files?

Tags: scala, sbt, generated-code

How do I refer to files generated by a `sourceGenerators` sbt task? I know that the source file is deposited to `target/scala-<version>/src_managed/path/to/File.Scala` but I don't know how to reference it in my project. Any ideas?

```
/server
  /app
    /models
      Driver.scala (can't use MyGeneratedCode here)
  /project
    /src/main/scala/
      ModelGenerator.scala  (the code used to create MyGeneratedCode.scala)
    /target/scala-2.12
      /classes
      /src_managed
        /main/generated/
          MyGeneratedCode.scala
```

Comment: You probably do not want to refer to the file itself, but to classes / objects / traits in them. If so, just as normal import them from their package and use them. What is the problem?

Comment: Can't figure out how to import the package... *nervous grin*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generate file works as any normal **Scala** file but on a fancy folder so it is not tracked by git *(or any other VCS)*.
As any **Scala** file, it should had a `package whatever` statement at the beginning, from which you can latter import your classes *(`import whatever._`)*. Usually the package name matches the directory structure, but they do not have to *(specially since it is just generated file)*.

If it does not have a package, all its members probably resides on the `__root__` package. But that probably would cause troubles, I would suggest editing your generator to add a package statement instead.

Comment: Perfect. Adding the `package` line is what helped!