# "object is not a member of package" when importing dependency built from another project via slick codegen

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, slick-codegen

I have a multi project setup like this:

```
lazy val kalosrpc = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion
    )
  ).dependsOn(kalosgen)

lazy val kalosgen = project
  .settings(
    // settings not important
  )
```

The main class of `kalosgen` generates a model via `slick-codegen` and places is it in:

```
kalosgen/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main
```

in the package `com.kalos.gen`. It also compiles protobufs into scala classes at compile time but that package is in the classpath as expected.

I can then import those files from `kalosgen` into `kalosrpc`, intelliJ does not complain and has full access to the type information defined in those files. So I run `kalosgen/compile` and the packages are generated as I expect however when I follow that up with `kalosrpc/compile` I get:

```
object gen is not a member of package com.kalos
```

I've tried changing the name of the packages but it doesn't fix anything. Based on the information [presented here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies) my project configuration seems correct.

Comment: Do generated files have `package somename` statements at the top?

Comment: yep, they have the package names I expect them to have. I tried setting the `kalosgen` project to output it's code in the `src_managed` dir of `kalosmodel` (instead of it's own `src_managed` dir) and it still does not work

Comment: Is it possible to publish a minimal example to an online repo?

Comment: I remade a minimal example but it works :\ there must be something wrong with my original project but in comparing the two I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was generating the sources in scala code via the `slick-codegen` utility:

```
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator

object Main extends App {
  val url = "hidden"
  val user = "hidden"
  val password = "hidden"
  val dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile"
  SourceCodeGenerator.main(
    Array(
      profile,
      dbDriver,
      url,
      "./kalosgen/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main",
      "com.kalos.gen",
      user,
      password
    )
  )
}
```

My guess is that you have to generate sources via SBT tasks to have them recognized by SBT as being valid sources (at least for the purposes of inter project dependencies), so I was able to translate the above code to a task that runs at compile time in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val gen = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "dependencies"
    ),
    sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val outDir = (sourceManaged in Compile).value.getPath
      (runner in Compile).value.run(
        "slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator",
        (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value.files,
        Array(
          "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile",
          "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
          "url",
          outDir,
          "com.kalos.gen",
          "username",
          "password"
        ),
        streams.value.log
      )
      Seq(file(outDir + "/com/kalos/gen/Tables.scala"))
    }.taskValue
  )
```

Now the generated `Tables.scala` appears as expected in the class path and my project compiles. If someone with more knowledge of sbt could provide a more comprehensive explanation of why this happened I will gladly accept it as the proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `show sourceManaged` from sbt which should output the location of where [generated files](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) should end up, for example in my project it is at

```
.../myproject/target/scala-2.13/src_managed
```

It likely should be

```
kalosgen/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main/com/kalos/gen
```

instead of

```
kalosgen/target/scala-2.13/main/com/kalos/gen
```

Also double check generated files have package [statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55927741/5205022) at the top.

Comment: that was a typo on my part, it is `/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main`